# Handling Java command line arguments in the format “cat file.txt | java YourMainClass”

Tags: java, terminal

I've never used java from the terminal before, and I certainly have never coded for it. My question is simple: How do I intake a file when the calling format is

```
cat  file.txt  |  java  YourMainClass
```

I have the rest of the code up and running swimmingly, I just need to take the given file name into my main method.

Comment: Something the answers below forget to spell out explicitly: you are NOT given a filename, just the input. Your example above is equivalent to `java YourMainClass <file.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the cat command displays the contents of the file, you need to use the System.in buffer to capture the data coming in from that command. You can use a BufferedReader pointing to System.in to loop through the data and process it.

Look at this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918525/piping-input-using-java-using-command-line)

```
public class ReadInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String x = null;  
        while( (x = input.readLine()) != null ) {    
            System.out.println(x); 
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to make the call from windows is there?

Comment: You could make a .bat file and have it execute the java call to your program at the command line. Or make it into a swing application that displays into a JFrame. The bat file would just contain the command like you typed it at the command line. I guess the best solution would change based on what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking to read from `System.in` as the output from `cat`, you could do:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // use line...
}
```