# Command line command on Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, command-line

[Handling Java command line arguments in the format “cat file.txt | java YourMainClass”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999357/handling-java-command-line-arguments-in-the-format-cat-file-txt-java-yourmain)

I saw the solution to my problem with the link above. However, I do not know how to run this using Eclipse. How do I use that command line argument? Should the text file be in the same folder as my program?

On another note, I am trying to run this using the command line in Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313270/how-to-make-eclipse-prompt-me-for-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0):

I can give you this suggestion.

Create a executable jar including the class which can read the text file as mentioned in that SO post and create a shell script to run the above command which executes the jar.

In Eclipse create an external tool configuration to execute a program which allows you to execute shell/dos commands. for example
go to Run->External Tools->External Tools then set up a new Program, with providing location
(ex: location to /bin/bash), working directory and relevant path variables in environment tab then add a command in the arguments section in that dialog similar to this.

```
"/bin/bash ./run.sh"
```

I have not personally tried it to run it with unix commands but created few external tool configs to use DOS commands like clean a target dir. Refer [this](http://blog.eflow.org/archives/64) too. Hope this will help.