# What do "empty line received or end of the input stream" mean?

Tags: java, io, console, stdin

I have a straight forward (except the question) task to be implemented on JVM language.
This is a simple command line program which expects some input from user and outputs result to console.

The confusing part to me is the following sentence "*STD input: input ends when an empty line is received or you reach the end of the input stream*".

The part with **empty line is received** I understood as user started the program from console and the program expects the user to enter the data by hand and empty line at the end:

```
$ java Main.class
Enter your data:
data1
data2

Result:
result1
result2
```

The program closes the console reader after user submitted empty line, processes data and prints the result to the console.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Although, the **you reach the end of the input stream** part is more vague to me. This makes me think that the program takes a whole input stream as argument.
In java it might look like this:

```
java Main.class file.txt
```

Is this what it really means?

This would make more sense in terms of testing my submitted code. The person who validates the correctness will execute my class against bunch of text classes and read the output of my program.

And again, if so, how would people automate the reading validation of the console output from a program?

What does the phrase "*input ends when an empty line is received or you reach the end of the input stream*" might mean? Should I cover both cases when user inputs data by hand and the case with file input stream?

Comment: If, for example, somebody redirects a file into standard in, then when the file has been read, the next read will cause an end-of-input. You can get this event with the console by typing a control-d at the start of a new line (at least on windows).

Comment: yup, I think you're right `java Class < file.txt` or the End of transmission character - is what they meant

Answer (score 2):

As [@NomadMaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9732672/nomadmaker) said in the comments, input can be piped. Check out this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918525/piping-input-using-java-using-command-line) for more details on this.